# Google ReCAPTCHA v2 bypass

Tags: php, email, security, recaptcha, spam-prevention

In Monday I deployed brand new version of website. There is contact form protected by Google ReCAPTCHA v2 Checkbox. Today I received first [spam (preview attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsQfp.png).

I mean. How is this possible? Backend implementation of verification is as bellow, I believe it's not possible to successfully submit contact form without confirmation from Google.

But still, the spam arrived!

```
    $name = $_POST['person__name'] ?? throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    $phone = $_POST['person__phone'] ?? throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    $email = $_POST['person__email'] ?? throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    $message = $_POST['message'] ?? throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    $type = $_POST['message__type'] ?? throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ?? throw new InvalidArgumentException();

    $url = sprintf(
            'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=%s&response=%s',
        urlencode('SECRET_RECAPTCHA_KEY'),
        urlencode($captcha),
    );

    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

    if ($response->success !== true) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Recaptcha');
    }
```

Comment: `I believe`...have you tested it throughly on the live site? Try to submit the data using a tool like Postman and see what happens. I suppose it's possible that someone actually completed the form manually with that spam data, but I agree it's unlikely. There are also tools which claim to be able to automatically solve catpchas - possibly someone managed to get one to work.

Comment: Sure I tried. But then this makes whole ReCAPTCHA useless isn't it? Yes, you can be protected against "stupid" bots which can't solve that. But when "clever" bot can find your form just 3 days after release..

Comment: Yeah it's a bit of an issue, I agree. I guess it's up to the captcha makers to try and make their captcha routines better. In terms of protecting yourself, you could try and up the defenses a bit with something like CRSF tokens as well, maybe. I'm sure others online in blogs etc have probably suggested other countermeasures which might be available as well.

Comment: yeah, spammers and bots can sometimes bypass or circumvent ReCAPTCHA measures...